# How does the FDC1004 (capacitance to digital converter) measure capacitance?

Tags: capacitor, adc, measurement, capacitance, switched-capacitor

I am using the [FDC1004](https://www.ti.com/product/FDC1004) and wondering how it exactly measures capacitance. The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/fdc1004.pdf) is not explaining much. An [associated application](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa927a/snoa927a.pdf) note contains a little more information, but still very little overall.

[image: FDC1004 - Topology]

The following picture summarizes how I understand the description.

[image: FDC1004 - Working principle]

But when I look at the CIN1 pin on the oscilloscope during a single measurement, the waveform looks a little different than expected.

[image: FDC1004 - CIN1 zoom]

[image: FDC1004 - CIN1]

1. Why are pulses emitted over a period of 10 ms for a single measurement process (at 25 kHz this makes 250 pulses)?
2. Why does the waveform of a pulse not correspond to a simple square
   wave?
3. How does the FDC1004 calculate the capacitance from these 250
   pulses?

Answer (score 0):

> *Why are pulses emitted over a period of 10ms for a single measurement
> process (at 25KHz this makes 250 pulses)*

Because an averaging process is used to minimize uncertainty.

> *Why does the waveform of a pulse not correspond to a simple square
> wave?*

Using bipolar pulses (positive and negative) is a good means of reducing offset errors. The fact that there are steps means (in my opinion) that when the drive waveform appears to be zero volts, it is in fact an open-circuit. Thus, the charge (tiny though it is) remains on the sensor electrode for long enough to be discharged into the switched capacitor circuit for processing and charge accumulation in all the 250 events that follow.

> *How does the FDC1004 calculate the capacitance from these 250 pulses?*

The accumulated charge becomes a voltage at the output of the switched capacitor circuit. That voltage is sampled and converted to a digital value. The value is proportional to voltage and the voltage is proportional to the accumulated charge and, the accumulated charge is proportional to sensor capacitance and number of accumulations. Given that there are 250 accumulations, capacitance is proportional to the digital value.